# Convert helm yaml values to cli executable

Tags: yaml, kubernetes-helm

how do I convert this yaml values in a way such that this become executable with helm install command?

```
  hostAliases:  
  - ip: "12.20.30.40"
    hostnames:
      - "001.stg.local"
```

i want to execute from terminal like this

```
helm install my-app -n my-namespace app/app1 \
--set hostAliases=[]
```

Comment: I'd recommend using the `helm install -f` option to pass in that YAML file as-is.  The `helm install --set` option has some unusual syntax and I wouldn't be confident in replicating that structure.  For some integration tasks it can help to know that JSON files are valid YAML, so if your tool can write out a JSON file it can work with `helm install -f`.

Answer (score 0):

values.yaml

```yaml
hostAliases:  
  - ip: "12.20.30.40"
    hostnames:
      - "001.stg.local"
      - "002.stg.remote"
  - ip: "0.0.0.0"
    hostnames:
      - "003.stg.local"
      - "004.stg.remote"
```

template/configmap.yaml

```yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test
data: 
  data: |-
   {{- range $idx, $alias := $.Values.hostAliases }}
   ip-{{ $idx }}: {{ $alias.ip }}
   {{- range $i, $n := $alias.hostnames }}
   host-{{ $idx }}-{{ $i }}: {{ $n }}
   {{- end }}
   {{- end }}
```

cmd

```bash
helm template --debug test .
```

output

```yaml
---
# Source: test/templates/configmap.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test
data: 
  data: |-
   ip-0: 12.20.30.40
   host-0-0: 001.stg.local
   host-0-1: 002.stg.remote
   ip-1: 0.0.0.0
   host-1-0: 003.stg.local
   host-1-1: 004.stg.remote
```

cmd

```bash
helm template --debug test . --set "hostAliases[0].ip=1.2.3.4" --set "hostAliases[0].hostnames={001,002}"
```

output

```yaml
# Source: test/templates/configmap.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test
data: 
  data: |-
   ip-0: 1.2.3.4
   host-0-0: 001
   host-0-1: 002
```